# Boolean array or String to store a bit string in Java Embedded System

Tags: java, embedded

To store a bit string in a Java program, running in an embedded system where is important the performance and to minimize the use of resources, is it better to use a boolean array or a string of characters?

Comment: On such a system, you wouldn't use Java in the first place. This isn't subjective but a fact. With a few very rare exceptions of Java VM implemented in silicon, like some experimental MCUs had 20 years ago, but no longer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much boolean values you have, I would suggest using `int` value, as it can store 32 bit values, if you want to have the value of the 3rd bit you can use something like:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=0;
        System.out.println((x & 0x04) >> 2);
        //set one at 3rd bit
        x=x | 0x4;
        System.out.println((x & 0x04) >> 2);
        //clear the 3rd bit
        x=x & 0xfffffffb;
        System.out.println((x & 0x04) >> 2);
}

}
```